# Consequence of the isomorphic relationship between the dual coset & subspace annihilator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,\|\ \|)$ be a normed vector space over $K$ and $M\subset X$ be a closed subspace. The annihilator of M is defined as
$$
M^{\bot}=\{f\in X^*:f(x)=0\;\;\forall x\in M\}\\
\big(\text{where  }X^*=\{f:X\to K\;\;|\;\;f\text{  is linear and bounded}\}\big)
$$
I want to prove that:
$$
\|[x]\|_{X/M}=\max_{f\in M^{\bot},\;\|f\|=1}{\lvert\ f(x)\ \rvert}
$$

I've already proved that:$\tag{*}\label{*}$
$A:M^{\bot}\to(X/M)^*$ given by $Af([x])=f(x)$ makes $((X/M)^*,\|\ \|_{(X/M)^*})$ and $(M^{\bot},\|\ \|_*)$ isomorphic.

So lets take any $x\in X$, fixed, and let $f\in M^{\bot}\text{  with  }\;\|f\|=1$. 
Clearly,
$$
\|[x]\|_{{X}/{M}}=\inf_{y\sim x}{\|y\|}=\inf_{y-x\in M}{\|y\|}=\inf_{y\in x+M}{\|y\|}=\inf_{m\in M}{\|x+m\|}
$$
Then, since $M^{\bot}\subset X^*$,
$$
|\ f(x+m)\ |\le\|f\|\|x+m\|=\|x+m\|\;\forall m\in M
$$
but $f(m)=0\;\forall m\in M$, so
$$
|\ f(x)\ |\le\|x+m\|\;\forall m\in M\\
\Rightarrow\ \sup_{f\in M^{\bot},\|f\|=1}{|\ f(x)\ |}\le \|x+m\|\;\forall m\in M\\
\Rightarrow\ \sup_{f\in M^{\bot},\|f\|=1}{|\ f(x)\ |}\le \inf_{m\in M}{\|x+m\|}\\
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\ \sup_{f\in M^{\bot},\|f\|=1}{|\ f(x)\ |}\le \|[x]\|_{X/M}\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Then, for another side, we get that:

$\quad$If $x\in M\Rightarrow\ [x]=[0]\Rightarrow\|[x]\|_{X/M}=0=|\ f(x)\ |\quad\forall f\in M^{\bot},\|f\|=1\\ \qquad\;\Rightarrow \|[x]\|_{X(M}=0=\sup_{f\in M^{\bot},\|f\|=1}{|\ f(x)\ |}$

$\quad$If $x\notin M\Rightarrow [x]\neq [0]\Rightarrow$ by Hahn-Banach, 
$$
\exists F\in (X/M)^*\text{ s.t. }F([x])=\|[x]\|_{X/M}\text{ and }\|F\|=1
$$
$$
\stackrel{\ref{*}}\Rightarrow\exists\;f\in M^{\bot}\text{ s.t. }F=Af
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\|f\|=1\text{  and  }\;|\ f(x)\ |=:|\ Af([x])\ |=|\ F([x])\ |=\|[x]\|_{X/M}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \sup_{f\in M^{\bot},\|f\|=1}{|\ f(x)\ |}\ge\|[x]\|_{X/M}
$$
Thereby, for any $x\in X$, fixed, we get
$$
\sup_{f\in M^{\bot},\|f\|=1}{|\ f(x)\ |}\ge\|[x]\|_{X/M}\stackrel{\ref{1}}\ge\sup_{f\in M^{\bot},\|f\|=1}{|\ f(x)\ |}
$$
thus
$$
\|[x]\|_{X/M}=\sup_{f\in M^{\bot},\|f\|=1}{|\ f(x)\ |}
$$
And here I got stucked trying to argue that the maximum of $\{|\ f(x)\ |: f\in M^{\bot},\|f\|=1\}$ is reached. Any ideas or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $M$ is closed, then $X/M$ is a normed space under the norm
$$
  \|[x]\|_{X/M}=\inf_{m\in M}\|x-m\|.
$$
By the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists $f^*\in (X/M)^*$ such that
$$
              f^*([x])=\|[x]\|_{X/M},\;\; \|f^*\|=1.
$$
Now consider $g^*\in X^*$ defined by $g^*(y)=f^*([y])$. This $g^*$ satisfies
$$
      g^* \in M^{\perp},\;\|g^*\| \le 1,\; g^*(x)=\|[x]\|_{X/M}.
$$